# Error occur in Visual Studio Environment

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, jchartfx

I am trying to create charts using jchartfx. I can trying with the example provided.my problem is when I run the HTML directly from the folder. its working and rendering the properly.But when I add that page into visual studio and try to run the app.I am getting the runtime Js Error.

here is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="jchartfx.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jchartfx.system.js"></script>
    <script src="jchartfx.coreBasic.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadChart()">

    <div id="ChartDiv" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

        var chart1;

        function loadChart() {

            chart1 = new cfx.Chart();
            chart1.getData().setSeries(2);
            chart1.getAxisY().setMin(500);
            chart1.getAxisY().setMax(2000);

            var series1 = chart1.getSeries().getItem(0);
            var series2 = chart1.getSeries().getItem(1);

            series1.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Lines);
            series2.setGallery(cfx.Gallery.Bar);

            var data = [
            { "Month": "Jan", "Bikes": 1800, "Parts": 1300 },
            { "Month": "Feb", "Bikes": 1760, "Parts": 900 },
            { "Month": "Mar", "Bikes": 1740, "Parts": 970 },
            { "Month": "Apr", "Bikes": 1750, "Parts": 1010 },
            { "Month": "May", "Bikes": 1810, "Parts": 1070 },
            { "Month": "Jun", "Bikes": 1920, "Parts": 1180 }
            ];

            chart1.setDataSource(data);

            var divHolder = document.getElementById('ChartDiv');
            chart1.create(divHolder);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Here is my tutorial link](http://support.softwarefx.com/jChartFX/article/2501235#2d0978a4-8c87-e211-84a5-0019b9e6b500)**.

> Error : Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefined

Any suggestion on why am getting this?

**Update:**

I have added `<meta content="IE=9" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />` in the head section it is working fine.but it gives the same error when I try to run the view in MVC application.

Is any meta tag will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` tag.

Comment: I have tried the code, but no luck. Still getting the same error.